# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - tell me what the heck is wrong in below SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-concatenation

```
declare @UnitIdn nchar(30);

set @UnitIdn = N'b';

set @UnitIdn =  @UnitIdn + N'aaaaa';

select @UnitIdn


set @UnitIdn = N'b';

set @UnitIdn =  N'aaaaa' + @UnitIdn 

select @UnitIdn
```

I know it will work if I change to nvarchar.

Comment: nothing, it runs just fine for me.  What error are you getting?  Or what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You need `nvarchar(30)`

Comment: trailing spaces issue because it's `nchar` and not `nvarchar`?

Answer (score 2):

That because `char` type has fixed length. So, you would need to do trim the blank space that has been reserved at the end of string.

```
declare @UnitIdn nchar(30);

set @UnitIdn = N'b';
set @UnitIdn =  rtrim(@UnitIdn) + N'aaaaa';
select @UnitIdn
```